# The best design pattern for creating dynamically JSON for API

Tags: php, json, api, design-patterns

I look for the most efficient and flexible design pattern for creating dynamically JSON that will be my API for IOS.

In example below (its only basic part) "pages", "container", "buttons" and "inputs" are dynamic. Their number and content depends request.

Now I create it that way:

```
foreach($pages as $page) {
    foreach($containers as $container){
        foreach($buttons as $burron){
           foreach($inputs as $inputs){

           }
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

```
{
    "callback": {
        "status": true,
        "message": "",
        "return_data": {
            "document": {
                "number": 6,
                "url": "/path/to/file",
                "document_id": 11,
                "type": 1,
                "date": "2017-10-30",
                "pages": [
                    {
                        "page_number": 1,
                        "container": [
                            {
                                "lp": 1,
                                "position": 0,
                                "buttons": [
                                    {
                                        "type": 1,
                                        "header": "Button name",
                                        "inputs": [
                                            {
                                                "type": 0,
                                                "x_pos": 160,
                                                "y_pos": 3441,
                                                "lp": 2
```

I hope that my question is clear. Thanks for all advice.

Comment: first of all you have to create a multi-dimensional array with this structure. and then convert it into the json format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The topic that you're describing is called [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). Basically, it's converting any data structure from one format to another. In your case you want to convert an object or array to JSON. There are several tools in PHP that help with that. For multidimentional arrays or `stdClass`es, you can use `json_encode()`. For more complex objects, you can use a serializer library, for example [JMS Serializer](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer).

Comment: So the topic is about creating dynamically that multi array. I need a pattern that will make this flexible.

Comment: There is no pattern that works as a silver bullet for building complex structures. You can use Factory or Builder pattern, as for any other object whose creation is non-trivial, but the implementation probably won't differ much from your code. Using a serializer is a solution that will likely require least code. Assuming you already have some kind of structure in place, you can map it to JSON using YAML or annotations.